# Positioning jQuery UI Widget

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've got a custom jQuery UI autocomplete that displays multiple columns.  This works great, as another developer was the one that created it, but I would like to make a change.

Currently the autocomplete dropdown positions itself so the top-left corner is aligned with the bottom left corner of the input text box.  However, due to the dropdown's width (displaying seven columns) extends out past the right side of the page, far enough that on a smaller monitor, it would be offscreen!

I could easily reposition the input box, but I'm looking to reposition the dropdown UI instead.  But I can't figure out *how.*  Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Current looks]

Nothing I've tried in the jQuery UI toolbox (`.offset()`,`.position()`) has worked as I can't seem to get a reference to the dropdown menu *itself.*  I've tried inside the _create method, _renderMenu, after targeting the input with `.mcautocomplete()`...either I end up offsetting the input box, get an error, or nothing happens.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gL5mef5t/)

Comment: I can't inspect a picture. Could you create a [mcve] for this? Or, if it's easier, could you provide a CSS selector for the dropdown UI element?

Comment: The drop down menu is built with jquery ui. It doesn't have a unique identifier. I'll throw together a fiddle after I finish lunch.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu added a fiddle.  There's only 1 item in the dropdown ("Item") as I had to separate it from the MVC backend.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI autocomplete includes a [`position` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-position) which uses the [position utility](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) to position the autocomplete popup.

Add something like this to your options ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gL5mef5t/2/)):

```
position: { my : "center top", at: "right bottom" }
```

Comment: Ah ha, I was trying to locate this, but found something that was only "close" (the `.position()` method) and then couldn't get a reference to the UI object.  I didn't see that it could be done as an option.  Thanks for the alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to your autocomplete using this logic:

```
$( elem ).autocomplete({ 
    source: ... 
}).autocomplete( "widget" ).addClass( "whatever" );
```

After that, you can style up that specific autocomplete. Here's an example:

```
.whatever {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0!important;
}
```

If you want it centered and know the width of your page you can go:

```
.whatever {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0!important;
  right: 0!important;
  width: 900px; /* or whatever your page has */
  margin: 0 auto!important;
}
```

The `important`s are necessary to override the inline style that is added by jQuery autocomplete itself.

Comment: Hmm.  While that worked in the fiddle, that it *not* work in my actual application, at least not when added to the CSS file.

Comment: This basically means you were not able to provide a [mcve]. You're missing the "Complete" part. :)

Comment: Thanks for the statement of the obvious.  I'm trying to figure out WHY that doesn't work, hence the "hmm."  The new style doesn't show up in Chrome's inspector, yet it should apply to that object.  Also, that would shove it all the way to the left side of the window, which I also don't want.

Comment: Ah, if I drop `form[action="./ConsumerFundCheckRequest.aspx"]` then it applies in the application, and it shoves it all the way left as I expected.  Page content is centered.  I only want to move it left about 300 pixels.

Comment: Check if the `action` parameter of the form on the server is identical to the one in the fiddle. I'm using it to only apply this to the `.ui-autocomplete` that follows it, not to other `.ui-autocomplete` you might have in your project. If this is the only one, just remove the `form[action="./ConsumerFundCheckRequest.aspx"] + ` from the selector. Alternatively, adjust the action according to your server's form.

Comment: You need to add `position: relative` to whatever parent you want your `.ui-autocomplete` aligned left to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98847/discussion-between-draco18s-and-andrei-gheorghiu).